# Matplotlib: Equal aspect ratio for one subplot only

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot an image and along with traces along two of its axes. I want shared axes (x for one trace and y for the other), no space between the plots but also an equal aspect ratio for the image. I work in Python 3.6.

With GridSpec (I have also tried with subplots), I can accomplish the first part:

[image: no_space]

However, if I force an equal aspect ratio on the image, I get this

[image]

It seems I cannot figure out how to have a square image with no spaces around...

Here is the relevant part of my code (I also have a version using subplots):

```
    h, w = plt.figaspect(1)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (h, w))
    grid = fig.add_gridspec(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, 
              hspace = 0, wspace = 0, width_ratios = [2, 1], 
              height_ratios = [1, 2])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,0])
    ay = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0], sharex = ax)
    az = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,1], sharey = ax)
    plt.setp(ay.get_xticklabels(), visible = False)
    plt.setp(az.get_yticklabels(), visible = False)

    # Add this for square image
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's some clever way of avoiding this problem altogether, but as a quick solution you could just use `subplots_adjust`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h, w = plt.figaspect(1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (h, w))
grid = fig.add_gridspec(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, 
          hspace = 0, wspace = 0, width_ratios = [2, 1], 
          height_ratios = [1, 2])
ax = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,0])
ay = fig.add_subplot(grid[0,0], sharex = ax)
az = fig.add_subplot(grid[1,1], sharey = ax)
plt.setp(ay.get_xticklabels(), visible = False)
plt.setp(az.get_yticklabels(), visible = False)

# Add this for square image
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Adjust subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
```

Though you'll want to alter the ticks somewhat, this gave me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That simple line did the trick, even though I also had to change the value of "top".